# Why not showing readme.md file content in packagist.org

Tags: composer-php

I made a composer package to make an archive by selecting files and folders. The public URL not showing readme content but is available in GitHub readme also I can see the readme content when I am logged in to packegist.org.

Package URL: https://packagist.org/packages/csesumonpro/phpzipmaker

GitHub URL: https://github.com/csesumonpro/phpzipmaker

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to name the file `README.md`? Also, how is this problem related to 7zip after all?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can try it. It's not directly related to 7zip, but this package can make 7zip. That's why I used this keyword.

Comment: If your question is not related to 7zip itself, please adjust the tagging

Comment: @NicoHaase, I have already tried it by README.md but not working.

Comment: @SumonSarker I can see that you've fixed the issue, can you add an answer on how you fixed it please? I would surely love to know!

Comment: @Studocwho,  I am doing nothing about it, at first I changed the readme.md to README.MD but it's not working that time. A few days later it has been populated automatically.

Comment: @SumonSarker Yeah apparently it gets held in a review queue until their staff reviews them. But you can get around that by emailing them directly, as I've just found out.